# swift spritekit how to run an action with a specified duration?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make my player change image once it detects collision with one of my game items and changes back after 0.3 seconds however, I dont know how to set the 0.3 duration for my image change? Currently the image changes in a flash

Here's my code:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()


     if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == "Poop" {
        let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("coinsound", waitForCompletion: false)
        run(sound)
        score += 1

        // Changes's player image to Poop once it collides with "Poop"
        let poopImage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Poop")
        let action = SKAction.setTexture(poopImage)
        firstBody.node?.run(action)


        scoreLabel?.text = String(score)
        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()
   }
}




  // Changes player's image back to what it was once it starts moving
  private func managePlayer(){
    if canMove{
        player?.move(left: moveLeft)
        player?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Player")
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside didBegin(_ contact) put your actions in a sequence like this

```
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([firstTextureChangeAction, SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.3), secondTextureChangeAction])
firstBody.node?.run(sequence)
```